Connecting Existing Records through explicit Many-to-many relation in prisma
I'm trying to connect two existing records through prisma.update to create an entry on an explicit many-to-many table. Can't figure out what I'm missing.
schema
model User {
    id        String   @id @default(uuid())
    cats UserCat[]

    @@map("users")
}

model Cat {
    id           String @id @default(uuid())

    users UserCat[]

    @@map("cats")
}

model UserCat {
    user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
    userId String
    cat    Cat     @relation(fields: [catId], references: [id])
    catId  String
    name   String?

    @@id([userId, catId])
}


I'm running:
await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
        id: newUserCat.userId
    },
    data: {
        cats: {
            connect: {
                userId_catId: {
                    userId: newUserCat.userId,
                    catId: newUserCat.catId
                }
            }
        }
    }
})

And getting an error:
Expected 1 records to be connected after connect operation on one-to-many relation 'UserToUserCat', found 0.

Are you sure your example code is correct? Your schema doesn't define a field User.userId_catId which you are trying to use to connect.

Found the answer I was looking for:
await prisma.userCat.create({
    data: {
        cat: {
            connect: {
                id: newUserCat.catId
            }
        },
        user: {
            connect: {
                id: newUserCat.userId
            }
        },
        name: newUserCat.name
    }
})

Simply could not find this in the Prisma documentation despite being so simple.
